# unable to reference Spring services in JUnit

Tags: spring, junit

i am running a Karaf container with a number of beans implementing the com.mycompany.foo.IMyBean interface. i refer to them as "child beans". each such "child" bean is registered as a service. i also have a single "parent" bean that rounds up all those "child" services by using osgi:list. everything works just fine in runtime. however, when i run a very simple JUnit scenario, i get the following exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'BeanRefsList': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   **Required 'bundleContext' property was not set**.

this is the context.xml in my JUnit project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd
    ">

    <bean id="ChildBean"
          class="com.mycompany.foo.ChildBean">
    </bean>
    <osgi:service id="ChildBeanService" ref="ChildBean" interface="com.mycompany.foo.IMyBean"/>

    <osgi:list id="BeanRefsList" interface="com.mycompany.foo.IMyBean"/>
    <bean id="ParentBean" class="com.mycompany.foo.ParentBean">
        <property name="childBeans" ref="BeanRefsList"/>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

the test class also contains the following annotation entries:

```
@org.junit.runner.RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration("context.xml")
```

please let me know what i am doing wrong. thank you for your time!

Comment: I faced the same issue, my workaround was to use two contexts: one just containing spring beans (this one I use in the tests) and another one that imports the former context (`<import resource="classpath:spring-only-context.xml"/>`) and additionally contains the OSGi stuff (in my case only exposing a service with `osgi:service`). It worked for me because in my tests I did not care about the OSGi service that I'm exposing, I just cared about the regular beans...

Answer (score 0):

The error message explains it pretty clearly.  The line that says

```
<osgi:list id="BeanRefsList" interface="com.mycompany.foo.IMyBean"/>
```

Needs too look more like

```
<bean id="ParentBean" class="com.mycompany.foo.ParentBean">
    <property name="childBeans" ref="BeanRefsList"/>
</bean>
```

Where the property "bundleContext" gets set properly.  I'm not familiar with OSGI, so I don't know what class/object needs to be set here.  But, that's what's missing.

I'm not sure what OSGI is looking for that's making it tell you "bundleContext" property is missing, but it sounds like both osgi:list and osgi:service use some kind of bundleContext property.

Have you specified all of the same imported schemas in jUnit that you did for your runtime context?

Comment: i fail to see how anything could be wrong with the osgi:list entry. according to section 6.2.2 in this doc, http://docs.spring.io/osgi/docs/1.1.x/reference/html/service-registry.html, the entry is correct. furthermore, even if i comment out the osgi:list line, i still get the exact same error regarding osgi:service entry.

Comment: does anyone else have any suggestions. i just cannot figure out why it is working during typical runtime, yet fails in JUnit. the bean and osgi entries in JUnit context xml were copied directly from the eclipse bundle project's context xml. does the JUnit one need to be adjusted in some way?

Comment: I do have one more suggestion, look into switching to Annotated classes in java instead of using XML, maybe?  In general, I find annotated Java much easier to read and debug than XML spring configurations - but that may or may not solve this issue. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s11.html